# Meteor custom type find

Tags: meteor

I have a JS custom type "Piece", and added it as a custom datatype to EJSON as per the doc. I store this in collection "PieceHolders" of generic object (since top level objects cannot be custom types) of the form: {piece: aPiece}.

In my Meteor method for insert, I first want to check for duplicate based on name and composer, such as
PieceHolders.findOne({"piece.name": "Sample1", "piece.composer": "PJD"});
Now this works fine on the client, but not on the server -- and hence I end up with duplicates. Why?
Because the Mongo doc looks something like this:
{ "piece" : { "EJSON$type" : "Piece", "EJSON$value" : { "EJSONname" : "Sample1", "EJSONcomposer" : "PJD", ...
and I am not searching accordingly for the server.

I was thinking of using transforms, but that massages the data after the find, not prior.  And needless to say, the same exact search needs to work on both the client and server.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

To match a field containing a custom type, use an instance of the custom type in the selector:

```
PieceHolders.findOne({
  piece: new Piece({name: 'Sample 1', composer: 'PJD'})
});
```

The above query will match an inserted document with the custom type:

```
PieceHolders.insert({
  piece: new Piece({name: 'Sample 1', composer: 'PJD'})
});
```

Ensure that the custom type is declared on both server and client

```
Piece = function (obj) {
  this.name = obj && obj.name;
  this.composer = obj && obj.composer;
}

Piece.prototype = {
  // typeName: function ...
  // clone: function ...
  // equals: function ...

  toJSONValue: function () {
    return {
      name: this.name,
      composer: this.composer
    };
  }
};

EJSON.addType("Piece", function fromJSONValue(value) {
  return new Piece(value);
});
```

---

As the OP pointed out, the above solution does not allow querying on selected properties of the EJSON custom type on the server. In this case, it would be better to use a transform on our Mongo collections instead of adding an EJSON type.

Let's say we want the `piece` field of a document to be returned as a `Piece` object when using *collection*.findOne() or *cursor*.fetch().

First, comment or remove `EJSON.addType` declarations related to `Piece`. Doing so allow us to store `Piece` objects in the database as JSON objects instead of its EJSON representation.

```
// Comment or remove lines below
//
// EJSON.addType("Piece", function fromJSONValue(value) {
//  return new Piece(value);
// });
```

Second, add or modify the transform option for any Mongo collections containing `Piece` objects. Replace any fields containing `Piece` objects with a call to its constructor.

```
PieceHolders = new Mongo.Collection('PieceHolders', {
  transform: function (doc) {
    if (doc.piece) doc.piece = new Piece(doc.piece);
    return doc;
  }
});
```

Lets test by inserting new documents and retrieving it.

```
PieceHolders.insert({
  piece: new Piece({name: 'name1', composer: 'Tom'})
});
PieceHolders.insert({
  piece: new Piece({name: 'name2', composer: 'Tom'})
});

PieceHolders.find({'piece.composer': 'Tom'}).fetch();
/* Should return the 2 documents we inserted!
[
  { piece: { name: 'name1', composer: 'Tom' }, _id: 'YFRiWHsTjQbFL7YSb' },
  { piece: { name: 'name2', composer: 'Tom' }, _id: 'd4SoeLfWrpRyXBe9y' }
]
*/

PieceHolders.findOne().piece instanceof Piece
/* Should return true! */
```

We can proceed to add more properties to `Piece` class and update its toJSONValue method if required.

Comment: Your solution as it stands does not help me because there is more to a Piece than just name and composer, but I only want to define a duplicate if there is a match on just both name and composer.  But a Piece can also have a catalogReference, as well as an array of measures etc.  Your approach works only if everything matches, and that's not what I want.

Comment: Or let's say I want to find all pieces by a certain composer.

Comment: I have expanded the answer. Let me know if it helps!

Comment: It actually works nicely, and I no longer need the 'holder' generic object wrapper (because 'top level objects cannot be custom types' is a restriction only for EJSON, not JSON). But I wonder when I would ever use an EJSON.addType declaration for a custom type.

Comment: Personally, as a core developer, I think EJSON custom types were a bad idea and are rarely the solution to problems. Especially not storing them in the database.

Comment: If we can't use EJSON for such objects, how do we let them be sent around in `Meteor.call` invocations?